# HtmlUnitDriver does not identified google sign in email textfied

Tags: selenium-webdriver, htmlunit-driver

Hi I had automated an login via Google functionality , it is working fine in Google Chrome but same code does not work when I had to run it to headless mode.

**org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element with ID: identifierId**

```
driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true);
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
wc = new WebDriverWait(driver, 3);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get(baseUrl);
driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId")).click();
```

I also tried wait command but no success . Please give me a solution

Comment: Please use latest version and post your complete case, with URL.

Comment: Can u give me the URL

Comment: Could be related to the information given in this answer: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/18696

Comment: use headless chrome instead of htmunitdriver